# Printing a 2 dimensional map in C

Tags: c, loops, printf

I have a game board to be printed with ASCII which I hope by the end looks something like this

```
            ___
3       ___/ 1 \___  ___
    ___/ 2 \___/ 2 \/ 3 \
2  / 1 \___/ 3 \___/\___/___
   \___/ 2 \___/        / 2 \
1  / 1 \___/ 1 \___     \___/
   \___/ 2 \___/ 2 \
0      \___/   \___/

     1   2   3   4
```

The map is distributed along x and y axis, size of the map is fixed too. The numbers to be printed are all stored in a 2d array. Some of them can be empty too as shown above.
Here's something that I tried to do. map->sizeX and map->sizeY gives the size of the X and y axis of the map. If the number in that block is 0, that means the block doesn't exists and we don't print it. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
void printMap(struct Map *map) {
    for (int i = 0; i < map->sizeX; ++i) {
        for (int k = 0; k < map->sizeX && i == 0; ++k)
            printf(" ___ ");
        printf("\n");
        for (int j = 0; j < map->sizeY; ++j) {
            if(i == 0) {
                printf("/ %d \\", giveFloe(map, i, j)->numbOfFish);
            }
            else {
                printf("/ %d \\", giveFloe(map, i, j)->numbOfFish);
            }
        }
        printf("\n");
        for (int l = 0; l < map->sizeX; ++l)
            printf("\\___/");
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

This is what I got as output, since I couldn't print the first row correctly, I didn't proceed. The map doesn't exceed 15 x 15 so I'm sure it can be printed on a terminal window.

```
 ___  ___  ___  ___  ___  ___  ___  ___  ___  ___ 
/ 3 \/ 0 \/ 2 \/ 0 \/ 2 \/ 0 \/ 3 \/ 0 \/ 1 \/ 0 \
\___/\___/\___/\___/\___/\___/\___/\___/\___/\___/
/ 0 \/ 0 \/ 0 \/ 2 \/ 0 \/ 1 \/ 0 \/ 3 \/ 0 \/ 3 \
\___/\___/\___/\___/\___/\___/\___/\___/\___/\___/
/ 2 \/ 0 \/ 3 \/ 0 \/ 3 \/ 0 \/ 3 \/ 0 \/ 1 \/ 0 \
\___/\___/\___/\___/\___/\___/\___/\___/\___/\___/
/ 0 \/ 1 \/ 0 \/ 2 \/ 0 \/ 2 \/ 0 \/ 2 \/ 0 \/ 3 \
\___/\___/\___/\___/\___/\___/\___/\___/\___/\___/
/ 3 \/ 0 \/ 0 \/ 0 \/ 2 \/ 0 \/ 3 \/ 0 \/ 1 \/ 0 \
\___/\___/\___/\___/\___/\___/\___/\___/\___/\___/
/ 0 \/ 3 \/ 0 \/ 2 \/ 0 \/ 1 \/ 0 \/ 3 \/ 0 \/ 1 \
\___/\___/\___/\___/\___/\___/\___/\___/\___/\___/
/ 3 \/ 0 \/ 2 \/ 0 \/ 2 \/ 0 \/ 3 \/ 0 \/ 2 \/ 0 \
\___/\___/\___/\___/\___/\___/\___/\___/\___/\___/
/ 0 \/ 2 \/ 0 \/ 3 \/ 0 \/ 3 \/ 0 \/ 2 \/ 0 \/ 2 \
\___/\___/\___/\___/\___/\___/\___/\___/\___/\___/
/ 3 \/ 0 \/ 2 \/ 0 \/ 3 \/ 0 \/ 3 \/ 0 \/ 2 \/ 0 \
\___/\___/\___/\___/\___/\___/\___/\___/\___/\___/
/ 0 \/ 2 \/ 0 \/ 3 \/ 0 \/ 1 \/ 0 \/ 3 \/ 0 \/ 3 \
\___/\___/\___/\___/\___/\___/\___/\___/\___/\___/
```

This is as far as I could get, it is assumed that the map won't exceed a terminal window. I am required for the map to look like the hexagons drawn above.

```
struct Map {
    struct Floe *mapPointer;
    int sizeX;
    int sizeY;
    struct Box *changelog;
    int changeCount;
    int maxChanges;
    struct Player *players;
    int playerCount;
};
```

`giveFloe()` takes in a the structure map and returns the `floe` on that coordinate.

```
struct Floe {
    int numbOfFish; 
    int whosPenguin; 
};
```

Comment: What output does your code produce?

Comment: Just an advice for the future, don't print directly to a screen. Use enough buffer to handle your map and use a sliding window to print a parts you would like to show to the user. It would allow you to have maps much bigger that your terminal window size. Of course you may use some custom buffer and basically convert it to printable area.

Comment: Your code has tow identical sequential conditions `if(i == 0) {`. They certainly have to be merged.

Comment: You say *"The map doesn't exceed 15 x 15 so I'm sure it can be printed on a terminal window."* Each cell needs 3 lines, so the 15 cell board will need 45+1 lines, usually larger than a terminal window. It is true that a Windows console is buffered and can be heightened or scrolled, but you could consider simpler cells such as `<1><2><3>`.

Comment: it would help if you told us how Map is defined.

Comment: You're asking for quite a lot of code to be written for you. You don't have a specific problem, and you're not asking a specific question, this means your question is too broad.

Answer (score 1):

I'm thinking your first step may be to re-think how the grid is laid out.

First of all how are you supposed to know which row each hexagon is supposed to be printed on (notice how my image treats each line as a row).

Second, is it legal to have two hexagons on the same row right next to each other? See hexagon `3` and `2` on the right side of the grid.

```
            ___
5       ___/ 1 \___  ___
4   ___/ 2 \___/ 2 \/ 3 \
3  / 1 \___/ 3 \___/\___/___
2  \___/ 2 \___/        / 2 \
1  / 1 \___/ 1 \___     \___/
0  \___/ 2 \___/ 2 \
       \___/   \___/

     0---1---2---3----4---5   <-- columns 4 and 5 don't fit normally
```